# Given a split exact sequence $0 \to N \to M \to M \to 0$, when can we say $N=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring $R$. Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$ such that there is a split exact sequence $0 \to N \to M \to M \to 0$. So, in particular, $M \cong M \oplus N$.

Under what additional conditions on $M,N$ or $R$, can we say that $N=0$ ?

Of course if $M$ is finitely generated, then $N=0$. What other conditions on $M$ or $N$ or $R$ would make that true (may be assuming $R$ Noetherian and something more ?) ?

Comment: Since even for $R$ a field (in particular Noetherian), if you allow infinitely generated modules, this is false, so can not expect much more.

Comment: Modules $M$ with this property are called “Dedekind finite”, or “directly finite” (although occasionally “Dedekind finite” also seems to be used to mean “co-Hopfian”: $M$ has no proper submodule isomorphic to itself). You’ll find quite a lot of literature about them by Googling.